# How are new std::map entries initialized just by key insertion?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have one `std::vector<MyString>` which data is not unique. Actually, most strings are repeated. And I have to find the unique ones and their repeat number.

I use map:

```
std::map<MyString,unsigned short> stringsMap;
.......
if ( stringsMap.find( currentString ) == stringsMap.end() )
{
    stringsMap[ currentString ] = 0;
}

stringsMap[ currentString ]++;
........
```

Do you have ideas how it could be done on fewer lines?

It could be done on one row: `stringsMap[ currentString ]++;` however short has indeterminate value by default.

Comment: The initial value is not indeterminate. It's 0. [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) value-initializes the value of any missing key.

Comment: Can you give me some confirmation on that?

Comment: Just get rid of the entire `if` statement.  If `[currentString]` doesn't already exist, it will be added and its value initialized to 0 before `operator++` is then applied to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It could be done on one row: stringsMap[ currentString ]++; however short has indeterminate value by default.

This is not true, value is well defined as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, **zero-initialized otherwise**) and a reference to it is returned.

emphasis is mine.

So it is perfectly fine to write one liner:

```
stringsMap[ currentString ]++;
```

and this is common practice and even given as an example in the documentation:

```
// count the number of occurrences of each word
// (the first call to operator[] initialized the counter with zero)
std::map<std::string, size_t>  word_map;
for (const auto &w : { "this", "sentence", "is", "not", "a", "sentence",
                       "this", "sentence", "is", "a", "hoax"}) {
    ++word_map[w];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> however short has indeterminate value by default.

No. For a non existing key the map will use `T()` to initialize the value of the newly created entry, which effectively evaluates to `0` for `unsigned short`.

See the [`std::map::operator[]` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) (emphasis mine<sup>1</sup>):

> > 1) Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist. This function is equivalent to `return insert(std::make_pair(key, T())).first->second;`
> >     - `key_type` must meet the requirements of `CopyConstructible`.
> >     - `mapped_type` must meet the requirements of `CopyConstructible` and `DefaultConstructible`.
> >     If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, **zero-initialized otherwise**) and a reference to it is returned.

Thus, writing just

```
std::map<MyString,unsigned short> stringsMap;
.......
stringsMap[ currentString ]++;
```

is perfectly fine.  The entire `if` block is redundant and not needed.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>That's not really true, it was [@Remy Lebau](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47660314/3)'s emphasis</sub>